# Retrieve AccountKey or ConnectionString from DocumentDB-Account using Pulumi

Tags: c#, azure, pulumi

I create a CosmosDB/DocumentDB - Account using AzureNextGen:

```
var databaseAccount=new Pulumi.AzureNextGen.DocumentDB.Latest.DatabaseAccount(accountName, 
  new Pulumi.AzureNextGen.DocumentDB.Latest.DatabaseAccountArgs
  {
    // parameters
  }
);
```

To be able to access this database afterwards I need to retrieve either the `key` or `connection string` of that databaseaccount:
[image]

I can build the first part of the connection string (the endpoint) via  `databaseAccount.DocumentEndpoint.Apply(q => "AccountEndpoint=" + q)` but I am stuck getting the more crucial part, the key.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure API doesn't return any sensitive data automatically. You need to run an explicit query for any secret data.

In this case, you should use functions [`listDatabaseAccountKeys`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-nextgen/documentdb/listdatabaseaccountkeys/) and [`listDatabaseAccountConnectionStrings`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-nextgen/documentdb/listdatabaseaccountconnectionstrings/) for this purpose. Here is a snippet in TypeScript:

```
const keys = pulumi.all([resourceGroupName, databaseAccount.name])
    .apply(([resourceGroupName, accountName]) =>
        documentdb.listDatabaseAccountKeys({ resourceGroupName, accountName }));

const connectionStrings = pulumi.all([resourceGroupName, databaseAccount.name])
    .apply(([resourceGroupName, accountName]) =>
        documentdb.listDatabaseAccountConnectionStrings({ resourceGroupName, accountName }));

const connectionString = connectionStrings.apply(cs => cs.connectionStrings![0].connectionString);
const masterKey = keys.primaryMasterKey;
```

Copied from [this example](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/azure-serverless-workshop/blob/master/03-telemetry/code/step2/cosmos.ts#L45-L55).

When translating to C#, you'd use `Output.Tuple` instead of `pulumi.all` like in [this template](https://github.com/pulumi/templates/blob/51f6a779a4ce5496310f410fe07b58410bbb889c/azure-nextgen-csharp/MyStack.cs#L32).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mikhails answer the C# - code to retrieve the primary key is as follows:

```
var keys = Pulumi.AzureNextGen.DocumentDB.Latest.ListDatabaseAccountKeys.InvokeAsync(
new Pulumi.AzureNextGen.DocumentDB.Latest.ListDatabaseAccountKeysArgs
{
  AcccountName = "databasename",
  ResourceGroupName = "resourcename"
});

var key = Output.Create(keys).Apply(q => q.PrimaryMasterKey);
```